# IntentService won't start using AlarmManager and broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I would like to fire an intentservice for echo 5 second periodically .
in the my intent service and broadcastreceiver I am using a `log.e` but I have not any log in logCat :

in my FragmentActivity :

```
public void scheduleAlarm(Context con) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(con, CheckNotificationPerEach12HourBroadC.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0,
            intent, 0);
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // first run of alarm is immediate
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
      }
```

---

my BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class CheckNotificationPerEach12HourBroadC extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(context, CheckNotificationPerEach12Hour.class);
    Log.e("CheckNotificationPerEach12HourBroadC", "fired");
   // i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    context.startService(i);
}

}
```

---

my IntentService :

```
public class CheckNotificationPerEach12Hour extends IntentService{

public CheckNotificationPerEach12Hour( ) {
    super("CheckNotificationPerEach12Hour");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("intent ser", "10 second");

}

}
```

in my manifest.xml :

```
    <receiver 
        android:name="com.shadyab.utilities.CheckNotificationPerEach12HourBroadC"
        android:process=":remote"
        >
    </receiver>  

    <service
        android:name="com.shadyab.utilities.CheckNotificationPerEach12Hour"
        android:exported="false"
         />
```

Comment: Do you want to run a method(which is in service) after every 5 sec?

Comment: no, I would like to run a method after every 12 hour periodically, now I want to examine it .

Comment: You can use timer task, i am mentioning it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service, and call it in your broadcast receiver.

```
public class ServiceTest extends Service {

private Timer mTimer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // getLogs();

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5 * 1000);

}


TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.wtf("service","running")

    }
};

}
```

Comment: actually I want to receive some data from MySQL (Even when my app is closed).

Comment: it will run,even if the application is closed

Comment: alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12, alarmIntent); It might work.